# VSC setup - Thorough and complete walk-through

Tags: c#, macos, installation, visual-studio-code

I've installed MS Visual Studio Code on my Mac (El Capitan OS). Basically, I want a C# editor and compiler, so I can learn how to code in C# and run those programs. I thought that, once VSC is installed, I would be set up and ready to go, but I've spent so many hours trying to get VSC to work, watching tutorials, reading posts and blogs.
I'm at this point where I've completely lost (and feel stupid). I don't know if someone can help me with a complete and thorough walk-through (keeping in mind that I'm new to all of this)?

So far, I've successfully installed VSC. But I have issues with the project.json and launch.json files (I don't even know where these files are supposed to be or to go) as well as a bunch of error messages.

If anyone could help me to go through the steps, I would be so thankful!

Comment: VSCode is just the editor. Use `dotnet new` at terminal to generate a new project (or use other ways to find suitable sample projects), and then you can edit it in VSCode. If you meet project.json/launch.json issue, post the exact issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a tutorial site. There are many tutorials and examples available that can be located through Google, Bing, or the Microsoft web site.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you have what you consider to be good tutorial to suggest? I've watched many, read many blogs, and that always led to dead-end. This is why I turned to this community. Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is just a editor. It just be able to edit text in source files (and debug). 
If you want to learn how to code on Mac. I suggest using Mono http://www.mono-project.com/download/
It is open-source cross platforms IDE for C#, it's easier to use for beginner.

Comment: Thank you for the precise and useful comment.